# Fonts provided by application not in Info.plist

Tags: fonts, jailbreak, tweak

I am developing a non-AppStore application and I would like to use some custom fonts in said app. Now I know that you can add custom fonts to your project by adding the "Fonts provided by application" key to your Info.plist and then just write down the font name. But my problem is that I am not able to use an Info.plist file in my app. So is it possible to use that key in a different .plist file and then load it into the project? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try entering 'UIAppFonts' as node key name and press enter. It must turn into 'Fonts provided by application'.